# In Windows, how do I do a mass search-replace where I search for a phrase and then copy the phrase with several different phrases?

Tags: windows, find-and-replace

I use Windows and I use a variety of text editors (NotePad++, Vim, etc). Any application works (since I'm willing to try any of the applications I have).

====

This is what I want to search.

```
vikenSurfaceTemps = vikenSurfaceTemps(vikenSurfaceTemps < 30);
MaxvikenDepths = MaxvikenDepths(vikenSurfaceTemps < 30);
```

I want to search/replace viken with a list of example words {undin,Soern,comet} and even more words, preferably with as little extra effort as possible.

So I'd like my final output to be something like this:

```
vikenSurfaceTemps = vikenSurfaceTemps(vikenSurfaceTemps < 30);
MaxvikenDepths = MaxvikenDepths(vikenSurfaceTemps < 30);
SoernSurfaceTemps = SoernSurfaceTemps(vikenSurfaceTemps < 30);
MaxSoernDepths = MaxSoernDepths(vikenSurfaceTemps < 30);
cometSurfaceTemps = cometSurfaceTemps(vikenSurfaceTemps < 30);
MaxcometDepths = MaxcometDepths(vikenSurfaceTemps < 30);
```

Comment: What program do you use? What OS?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could clarify what OS you're using, whether a solution using a Unix shell and tools like `sed` would be acceptable or if it must be done with Windows `cmd.exe`, whether this is a single file to be modified or multiple files and whether `{undin,Soern,comet}` is a literal string or a list of example words.  A couple clear examples of before and after would really help.

Comment: Okay - updated. :)